# XMLHttpRequest is throwing an error for non-200 statuses

Tags: http, post, xmlhttprequest

To validate a login on my website, I send a POST request to the server. If it returns a `403` status, that means the credentials were incorrect, and a `200` status means the login was successful.

This is the code I'm using to send that request:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
var form = document.getElementById("login")

req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState !== 4) return

    if (req.status === 200) {
        console.log(req)
    } else if (req.status === 403) {
        document.getElementById("login-err").innerHTML = req.responseText
    } else {
        document.getElementById("login-err").innerHTML = "internal server error"
    }
}

req.open("POST", `https://${window.location.host}/newsession`, true)
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
req.send(`username=${form.username.value}&password=${form.password.value}`)
```

It works fine for `200` statuses, but when the status is `403` (or `500`), an error is logged to the console: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`.

Though it's not a *huge* problem, I would expect that, since I'm handling the status code, there shouldn't be an error. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to prevent it see this link: [Possible to prevent 403 errors from logging to the web console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154059/possible-to-prevent-403-errors-from-logging-to-the-web-console)